# Angular 2 - Karma testing Service that returns Observable doesn't see spy getting called

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have a service/interceptor that returns an Observable. I see **loadOverlayService.start** and **next.handle** both have been called. However 
**mockLoadOverlayService.popHttpRequest** has 0 calls recorded against it in the spy.

What am I doing wrong?

**interceptor.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class OverlayInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private loadOverlayService: LoadOverlayService) {
  }

  protected intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loadOverlayService.start();

    return next.handle(request)
      .do(
        // Start, do nothing
        () => {},
        // Error
        () => this.loadOverlayService.stop(),
        // Complete
        () => this.loadOverlayService.stop()
      );
  }
}
```

**interceptor.spec.ts**

```js
describe('OverlayInterceptor', () => {
  let mockLoadOverlayService: any;
  let mockHttpHandler: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockLoadOverlayService = jasmine.createSpyObj('LoadOverlayService', ['pushHttpRequest', 'popHttpRequest']);
    mockHttpHandler = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpHandler', ['handle']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        OverlayInterceptor,
        {provide: LoadOverlayService, useValue: mockLoadOverlayService}
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should show then hide modal', async(inject([OverlayInterceptor], (interceptor: OverlayInterceptor) => {
    const request = new HttpRequest("GET", "someClientTypeCheckUri");

    buildMocksForSuccessfulOutcome();

    interceptor.intercept(request, mockHttpHandler).subscribe(res => {   
      expect(mockHttpHandler.handle).toHaveBeenCalledWith(request); // Works
      expect(mockLoadOverlayService.pushHttpRequest.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'PushHttpRequest was called 1 times'); // Works
      expect(mockLoadOverlayService.popHttpRequest.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'PopHttpRequest was called 1 times'); // Doesn't work
    });
  })));

  function buildMocksForSuccessfulOutcome(): void {
    mockHttpHandler.handle.and.returnValue(Observable.of(null));
  }
});
```

Comment: I see that your `OverlayInterceptor` says it implements `HttpInterceptor` but I don't see the `intercept` method that the interface has on your class. Did you mean to have your `protected process()` method to be that `intercept()` method? https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/common/http/src/interceptor.ts#L27-L45

Comment: Oops - a mistake with my copy and paste - now fixed - thanks